# Can I create a "sparse" index by using a partition key that is sometimes not present?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html) I can read that I can create a so called "sparse" index (similar to a partial index in e.g. postgresql) by making the GIS on a `sort key` that is not always present. Does the same count for the `partition key`? So in the example from the documentation, if the key `CustomerId` is sometimes missing but the `OrderId` is always there?

In other words: I would like to index only records that has a `CustomerId` but I want `CustomerId` as partition key, not sort key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is very misleading; and Charles's answer is somewhat misleading, because in the example, `CustomerId` is the partition key of the table.

A Dynamo table has a key that may be just a partition key, or may be made of a partition key and a sort key.  The same is true for a Global Secondary Index.

You cannot insert into a table an item having a null value for the key attributes.  In the example in the documentation, the table has partition key `CustomerId` and sort key `OrderId`, so both of those attributes must be set for an item to be inserted.

However, if the table has other attributes, such as `isOpen` and `OrderOpenDate`, these can be nullable, and so used to make a sparse index.  For instance, you can create a GSI with partition key `isOpen` and sort key `OrderOpenDate`, and only those items which have both of those attributes set will appear in the index.

This matches the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.StorageConsiderations):

> If a table contains an item where a particular attribute is not defined, but that attribute is defined as an index partition key or sort key, DynamoDB doesn't write any data for that item to the index.

The answer to the broader original question is: Yes, you can make a sparse index where the partition key of the index is a nullable attribute of the table.  Only those items where that attribute is set will appear in the index.

Answer (score 0):

No, a partition key is always required.  So you couldn't use CustomerID as the partition key on a GSI.

You could use a fixed set of integers from [1..N] including using just 1.  So you'd only have a single partition; as long as your data is < 10GB and your required read and write capacity are within limits for a single partition (3000 RCU 1000 WCU).

Comment: I'm not sure I have explained myself well enough maybe. It's my understanding that creating a "sparse" index can be useful for having small effective indexes at at subset of records from a table, for which an attribute is present, and not present to the rest of the records. In my case, I have an attribute: `CustomerID` which is NOT always present and another `CreatedAt` which is always there for all records in the table. I want to index ONLY those records which has a `CustomerID`, but I wanna use `CreatedAt` as sort key, so I can find all records with CustomerID = 123 between some dates.

Comment: I understand your question...customerID would not be a valid choice for partition key since it isn't always present.

Comment: But, what would the problem be? Wouldn't it just mean, that only records WITH a CustomerId would be found in the index - which is exactly what I want? :-)

Comment: Dynamo won't allow it.